# Serialize an intent in Android?

Tags: java, android

i want to serialize an intent after i rcv it using `ObjectOutputStream`  , but i got this exiption

`java.io.NotSerializableException: android.content.Intent`

is there away so i could serialize the intent, thanks.

Comment: As `Intent` does not implements the `Serializable` interface, it cannot be serialized. What kind of information are you saving in the `Intent` that you want to serialize? And... why would you want to serialize an `Intent`?

Comment: i want to serialize the extra in the intent without worrying about handling the extra one by one when im writing it , could i get all the extra using getExtras() and then serialize the bundle ?.

Comment: i found out that bundle is not Serializable .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest you can get is to flatten it via the Parcelable protocol, and get the byte[] from marshall() method.